# Find a function such that f(x)/P(X > x) is a constant.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What do you think of the following question?

"Let X be a continuous random variable such that $P(X\le 0) = 0$. Let $f(·)$
be its probability density function. Suppose that $f(x)/P(X > x)$ is equal
to a constant $a$ for all x > 0. What is the distribution function of X?"

Well, it appears to me that the answer is an exponential but I don't seem to be able to match it to the boundary conditions i.e. $P(X=0) = 0$ and $P(\infty) = 1$.

Any help?

Comment: What exactly do you think is an exponential, $f(x)$, $P(x>x)$, or the distribution function $F(x)$?  And what exponential do you think it might be?

Comment: It is not required that $f(x)/P(X > x)$ is a probability distribution. Thus  it is not necessary that the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: It would be an exponential distribution. Please show your working as I can prove the boundary conditions. A first order ODE with constant coefficients should be part of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I share with you the solution to the problem you pose. Your hypothesis can be summarized as follows:
$$
\frac{f(x)}{P(X>x)} \quad \forall x> 0,\quad \mathrm{ and } \quad P(X\leq 0)=0.
$$
The last condition implies that the cumulative distribution function $F$ is zero for $x\leq 0$, so it is sufficient to characterize $F$ for $x>0$. Assuming $x>0$, we have that
$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=a\frac{dP(X>x)}{dx}=a\frac{d(1-P(X\leq x))}{dx}=-a\frac{dF(x)}{dx} \Longrightarrow \frac{df(x)}{dx}=-af(x).
$$
Therefore, it all boils down to solving a separable differential equation, making it easy to solve. Omitting the steps to obtain that solution, we have that the f must be of the form
$$
f(x)=\kappa e^{-a x}.
$$
where $k$ is a constant of integration, but since $f$ must be a density, $\kappa$ must be $a$, so we can conclude that $f$ must be an exponential probability density.

Comment: Dear Diego,

Yes. Thank you very much for helping me. Much obliged!